# Ansible: Convert a complexe dictionary to java properties

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am wondering if there is an easy way to convert such a dictionary

```
  sql:
    alter_table: true
    store:
      driver: org.postgresql.Driver
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
```

to properties like that

```
sql.alter_table = true
sql.store.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
sql.store.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
```

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use a custom filter. For example

```
$ cat filter_plugins/dict_utils.py
def dict_flatten(d, separator='.'):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + separator)
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + separator)
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(d)
    return out

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'dict_flatten': dict_flatten
        }
```

The task

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ sql|dict_flatten }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": {
        "alter_table": true, 
        "store.driver": "org.postgresql.Driver", 
        "store.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"
    }
```

Prepend the name of the variable to get the required output. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        my_dict: "{{ {}|combine({'sql': sql}) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_dict|dict_flatten }}"
```

give

```
    "msg": {
        "sql.alter_table": true, 
        "sql.store.driver": "org.postgresql.Driver", 
        "sql.store.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, interessting code !
But i find the complexity a bit too high.
So I ended up reworking the role to use flat variable from the begining:

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using directly flat vairables like

```
properties:
  sql.alter_table: true
  sql.store.driver: = org.postgresql.Driver
  sql.store.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
```

and then looping over them with dict2items

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.key }} = {{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ properties | dict2items }}"
```

The only difference I see, is that you have to use the variable like this

```
properties['sql.store.url']
```

instead of

```
properties.sql.store.url
```